# Do not select returned item in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help me out with this issue. I have a jquery autocomplete box populated via AJAX. What the PHP on the server side does is lookup a specific client's contact number, based (obviously) on what you entered. If it doesn't find the contact number, it returns with "Continue typing to add the new client contact number".

Now this is working fine, I only want to know whether there is some way where, when that text is displayed, if the user hits tab, the option won't be selected and overwrite what has already been entered into the textbox, but simply move onto the next field.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the categories example for Autocomplete.

You can make your message a type of category header, and as such it wouldn't be selectable by the user.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

The example works by implement their own `_renderMenu` method. I've done this and it wasn't too hard, but it did require a newer version of jQuery to work.